# Ubuntu secure boot grub bootloader doesnot verify custom kernel signature

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I want to do secure boot ubuntu with our custom keys,Trusted chain of booting should be from bios to bootloader and bootloader to  kernel,every step of loading next stage after verifying with our custom signatue.

I have signed ubuntu bootloader(grubx64.efi,mmx64.efi and shimx64.efi), kernel(vmlinuxz) and initrd.

I have generated private key with public certificate(PK,KEK,DB) using openssl and signed all the things using sbsigntool and I have put all the keys in Bios.
Bios only allows to load bootloader only if it is signed same keys present in Bios it is ok.and the problem is bootloader allows kernels without verifying signature ,bootloader allows the kernel although it is signed with different keys.What needs to do so that bootloader will verify kernel?I have set check_signature enable in grub configuration file.then also it is not verifying the signature.what needs to do?